TLS 1.3 key derivation and length of labels used (RFC 8446)
Out of sheer curiosity, I've been referring to RFC 8446 and implementing a TLS 1.3 client. I've implemented traffic key derivation as described in section 7.1 of the RFC.
There is a note in the last paragraph of section 7.1 (page 91) (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-7.1) stating that the labels used in the RFC do not exceed 12 octets in length. It also mentions that common hash functions require an additional iteration when the length of the labels is longer than 12 characters.
I do not understand this entire paragraph. I don't know which hash functions the RFC is referring to. Also, I cannot see how it is relevant especially when HKDF used for key derivation.

"I don't know which hash functions the RFC is referring to." - to cite: "The Hash function used by Transcript-Hash and HKDF is the cipher
suite hash algorithm."

Yes, thanks, but I still don't see the meaning of label lengths - especially 12 character limit. Also, what is the "additional iteration" if we consider SHA256 or SHA384? At least for me, the language there (in the RFC note) is not very clear.

HKDF-Extract consists of a function that uses HMAC, which in itself relies on a hash. So what we need to do is to work backwards from that.
We'll assume SHA-256 with a 64 byte block size as SHA-512 has a bigger block size of 128 and is therefore unlikely to be the limiting factor, even though it uses 17  bytes for padding and length encoding instead of the 9 for SHA-256. Note that SHA-3 is not mentioned in the RFC.

Let's first look at the algorithms used:

The capacity of a single run of the inner SHA-256 on the final block including padding is 64 - 8 - 1 = 55 bytes. The 8 bytes are required to encode the size of the message in bits, and one byte is required for the bit padding. All input before that is processed block by block, which is important for the HMAC function.

SHA-256 is used in the HMAC function where the key $K'$ is used, padded with $opad$ which is the block size. That means we can safely ignore the HMAC function here to calculate the minimum, as the key simply takes a full block before the final one.

The way HMAC is used in PBKDF-Expand removes one byte from the total for a counter, leaving us with 54 bytes. We only need one block as output, otherwise the output of the previous hash would also be included, skewing the results.


So we have 54 bytes to work with in the final block which is going to contain the label.

The label is not used directly in the definition of TLS. We can see that:
struct {
    uint16 length = Length;
    opaque label<7..255> = "tls13 " + Label;
    opaque context<0..255> = Context;
} HkdfLabel;

Here the size of the label and context fields are prefixed as a single byte to the byte arrays (or vectors in TLS parlor that they represent. Note that the 7 in <7..255> assumes that the label is at least one character.
These are the components of the structure in bytes, except for the label:

length: 2 bytes (uint16)
label length field: 1 byte (since the label length ranges from 7 to 255, it fits in 1 byte)
"tls13 " string: 6 bytes
label: the max size of which we try to calculate
context length field: 1 byte (since the context length ranges from 0 to 255, it fits in 1 byte)
context: 32 bytes (given)

if we calculate the final tally of the known bytes sizes we have:
$$2 + 1 + 6 + 1 + 32 = 42$$
Now we can do the final calculation: $54 - 42 = 12$ bytes left in the block for the label.

Alternatively the calculation can also be found on the TLS 1.3 mailing list.
